SObject was retrieved without querying error not raised as expected
Generally, if a field is not retrieved from SOQL and is used in code later, it raises the well known exception " SObjecte row was retrieved without querying field...". However, this behavior is not seen in following example when run in execute anonymous:
//Does not give error (even if it's accessed/being modified later)
Account a = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account limit 1];
a.billingcity = 'asdsa';
system.debug('dfdsf : ' + a.billingcity);
update a;

The following code give the error though (even if it's just mentioned in debug statement , not modified upon):
//Gives error: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Account.BillingCity
Account a = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account limit 1];
//a.billingcity = 'asdsa';
system.debug('dfdsf : ' + a.billingcity);
update a;

What could be the possible reason for this? Any relevant documentation regarding this helps. Though this observation does not add value in coding as we should always query the field that is being modified, but I am curious to know the backend logic behind the error shown vs. not shown.

The exception only occurs if you try to read the value before it is populated by query or by direct modification. In the first example, Apex does not throw the exception because you assigned a value to the field before trying to read it. The second example throws the exception because you did not assign a value, nor queried the field, and tried to read the value. Also note that this error only applies to queried records. If you constructed the record yourself, it won't throw the exception:
Account a = new Account();
System.debug(a.BillingCity); // Outputs "null", no exception thrown


...we should always query the field that is being modified...

You should never query the field that is being modified. You should always query the field that is being read. In other words, your understanding is the exact opposite of what we should do as developers.
